# Java How to update time elpased for specific objects

Tags: java, timer

I'm programming a Kitchen Display System where it takes orders from the counter and post it I'm having troubles with the `Timer` my problem is that when an order is received the timer restarts to 0

here's my code

```
private void addComponent()
{
    //////component adding codes

    final Calendar startTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    timer.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
       @Override
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
       {
           String x;
           DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("00");
           long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
           long diff = endTime - startTime.getTimeInMillis();
           int h = (int) (diff) / (60*60*1000);
           diff -= h * (60*60*1000);
           int m = (int) (endTime-startTime.getTimeInMillis()) / (60*1000);
           diff -= m * (60 * 1000);
           int s = (int) (diff / 1000);
           //time.setText(df.format(h) + ":" + df.format(m)+ ":" + df.format(s));
           x=df.format(h) + ":" + df.format(m)+ ":" + df.format(s);
           time.setText(x);
           revalidate();
           repaint();
       }
    });
    timer.start();
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    KitchenStation frame=new KitchenStation();
    frame.setSize(1000, 600);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    do
    {
        try
        {
            frame.gui.removeAll();
            frame.addComponent();
            frame.getContentPane().validate();
            frame.getContentPane().repaint();
            frame.receiveFile();
        }catch(IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }while(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try set Timer outside the methods and save it when it starts like this:

```
public Timer timer;

private void addComponent()
{
    //////component adding codes

    final Calendar startTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    timer.addActionListener(new ActionListener()

//...
```